# The process created by Python 3 cannot be executed on windows

Tags: python

I wrote a simple program and created a process. I don't know why I didn't execute it. **print(name)** not executed.my python IDLE version is 3.10.0.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def test_func(name):
    print(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=test_func, args=('test',))
    p1.start()

    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: What's happening for you? It works fine for me on Windows

Comment: Works on my windows

Comment: I thought my program would print test, but it didn't.